# Will a very long space ship orbiting the Earth appear to have gravity to someone inside?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, centrifugal-force, satellites

My friends and I have several disagreements about this scenario:
Imagine a rigid cylinder that is the length of the diameter of the earth. At either end of this cylinder is a capsule with a person inside.

Disagreement 1: Assuming that this space ship can be placed in a stable orbit around the earth, what orientations would be stable? Could the ship be made to orbit the earth such that it is parallel with the rotational axis of the earth?

Disagreement 2: If you could create a ship like this, orbiting the earth parallel to it's rotational axis, what would the experience be like inside one end of the capsule? If the two capsules were not connected by the cylinder, they would follow the great circle orbits and therefore approach each other. Wouldn't then a person floating inside the capsule at one end feel himself pulled toward the floor of the capsule as his body tries to follow that orbit?
Second, since the cylinder is so long, the ends of the cylinder are further from the earth than the center. However, the ends of the cylinder would be orbiting according to the center of mass of the cylinder, which, being in a lower orbit, would be faster than a body orbiting at an orbit the same distance from the earth as the end of the cylinder. Thus the ends of the cylinder would be moving faster than a body in orbit. Would this appear as a continuous force to the observer in the capsule? Or would the observer simply hit the side of the capsule, be accelerated, and then continue to float in zero g?

Please help us resolve this disagreement.

Comment: Note that the size of the structure *relative to its orbital radius* is what matters, not the size relative to the Earth's size. (For most calculations, the size of the Earth is irrelevant due to the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem).)

Comment: Welcome to physics SE. If you limit your questions to one question per question, you will tend to get more and better answers; questions which ask multiple questions may be closed for lack of focus.

Comment: *"a rigid cylinder that is the length of the diameter of the earth."* Making it rigid is *very* difficult. What's the diameter of the cylinder?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on skyhooks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_(structure) may be of interest - although a skyhook is much smaller than the structure that you are proposing.

Comment: The gravity that inhabitants of a large orbiting body would experience is explored in Greg Egan's excellent novel "Incandescence".

Answer (score 5):

**Yes due to tidal forces**

The gravitational accelerations aren't the same everywhere, they increase closer to Earth under the inverse square law. Also important is that the *direction* of the force varies.

**Small ship, non rotating:** for this we can assume the center of mass of the ship orbits the Earth. At the center of mass there is weightlessness: the gravity is exactly cancelling out the ship's acceleration. The "earthward" decks feel gravity toward Earth. Conversely, in the "spaceward" decks "down" is *away* from Earth since Earths gravity there is weaker than the ship's acceleration. If you travel away from the center of mass "horizontally" "down" is back toward the ships center of mass (due to the changing direction of Earths gravity). Both effects grow very slowly with distance from the center of mass.

**Large ship:** (large with respect to its orbit): This case is more complicated. The ship generally will *not* have it's center of mass in weightlessness. Instead, Earths gravity will pull on each bit of ship mass according to inverse square law. The (very strong) ship stays rigid and may chaotically orbit and/or spin. The gravity in each part is the *difference* between the acceleration of said part and Earth's gravity at that point.

A long cylinder will tend to point with one end towards Earth and one end away from Earth. At both ends "down" is away from the center of the cylinder. This configuration is generally stable, but will be unstable if the rod is too long.

**Edit: Instability of a long rod in orbit:**

Consider a long, uniform rod of tidally locked to a point mass in a circular orbit. The stability does not depend on the rod and planet mass (so long as the planet is much heavier than the rod); lets set the rod mass to 1 and the planet mass to G.

If the total energy is positive then the system will become unstable (I think): the rod will tend to spiral in to the planet or out to infinity. There is no local "potential well" to prevent this from happening. Unlike a planet in a circular orbit (or in any bound orbit), we can get positive total energy for a long enough rod.

The near-end (far-end) of the rod is at $r=r_0$ ($r=r_1$). By integrating the inverse-square force from $r_0$ to $r_1$, we see that the rod's gravitational acceleration is $a=1/(r_0 r_1)$ (a tiny spaceship would have $r_0 \approx r_1$ and we would get the standard inverse-square force). The center of mass is at $r_c=1/2(r_0+r_1)$, which requires a rotation rate of $w=\sqrt{a/r_c} = \sqrt{1/(r_cr_0r_1)}$ in order to be in circular motion. Just as in ordinary planet orbits, multiplying the both $r_0$ and $r_1$ by 4 will increase the period by *8*.

The kinetic energy of the rod is from both it's linear and angular velocity:

KE = (translation)+(rotation) = $1/2r_c^2w^2+1/2Iw^2 = (1/2w^2)(r_c^2+1/12(r_1-r_0)) = 1/(2r_cr_0r_1)(r_c^2+1/12(r_1-r_0)^2)$.

The gravitational potential energy is also commuted by integrating across the length of the rod, and we get: $V=ln(r_0/r_1)/(r_1-r_0)<0$. This equation is undefined at $r_0=r_1$ where both the numerator and denominator are zero. But if we set $r_1$ extremely close to $r_0$ the energy becomes the point-mass value of $V=-1/r_0$.

Instability sets in once kinetic is greater than minus the depth of the potential well:

$-ln(r_0/r_1)/(r_1-r_0)<1/(2r_cr_0r_1)(r_c^2+1/12(r_1-r_0)^2)$

Define $x=r_1/r_0$. This is the relevant *dimensionless parameter* that we care about. The larger this ratio the less "point-mass-like" the rod is. Lets write each side in terms of $x$ and $r_0$:

$ln(r_1/r_0)/(r_1-r_0)<1/((r_0+r_1)r_0r_1)(1/4(r_0+r_1)^2+1/12(r_1-r_0)^2)$

$(1/r_0)ln(r_1/r_0)/(r_1/r_0-1)<(1/r_0)(1/(1+r_1/r_0))(r_0/r_1)((1/4(1+r_1/r_0)^2+1/12(r_1/r_0-1)^2)$

$(1/r_0)ln(x)/(x-1)<(1/r_0)(1/(x(1+x)))(1/4(1+x)^2+1/12(x-1)^2)$

$-V=(1/r_0)ln(x)/(x-1)<(1/r_0)\frac{x^2 + x + 1}{3 x^2 + 3x}=KE$

What happens in the limit of large $x$ for a given $r_0$? The potential energy becomes less negative, since more of the spaceship (which keeps a constant mass, i.e. we make it less and less dense) is further away. The center of mass grows in direct proportion to $x$. But the total force of gravity only drops off like $1/x$ instead of $1/x^2$; because $1/x$ of the spaceship stays "close" to the planet. Because of this quirk, maintaining circular motion requires the ship's velocity and kinetic energy to converge to a constant.

Where precisely does the circular orbit become unbound? Set the inequality to an equality and simplify the equation:
$ln(x)=\frac{x^3 - 1}{3 x^2 + 3x}$

This equation can't be solved on pen and paper. But numerically, it has three solutions: $x \approx 1/6.505, x=1, x \approx 6.505$ (I may have made a minor mistake with the constants but the scaling should work). The first and last solution are physically equivalent. The $x=1$ solution is extraneous. Thus we are looking at about a 6:1 ratio before instability sets in. If one end is at low earth orbit the other end would need to be about 35000km above the Earths surface (which happens to be about the geostationary orbit height) before the orbit becomes unstable to radial perturbations. A real space elevator would likely have most of it's mass concentrated in it's middle for the same reason skyscrapers are bigger at the bottom. This would make it more stable then these uniform-density calculations assume.

**General relativity**: A perfectly rigid object is impossible, even in principle, in relativity because the speed of sound in it's material would exceed the speed of light. Thus one would need to have a model for how the material deforms under load.

Comment: Could you  expand on why, if the ship is long enough, even the 'tidally locked' configuration is unstable? How long is long enough in this case?

Comment: @Prallax: I expanded it. A LOT.

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you! It's a very cool instability

Answer (score 3):

##### Yes, people inhabiting a very large spaceship would feel [tidal forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force).

Tidal forces would tend to stretch the ship toward and away from the Earth while compressing it along the perpendicular directions, like this, if the Earth is to the left or right:

[image: tidal force diagram]
[[image source](http://burro.astr.cwru.edu/Academics/Astr221/Gravity/tides.html)]

The longitudinal stretching effect arises because the side of the ship that is closer to the Earth is pulled toward the Earth more strongly, while the side that is farther from the Earth is pulled toward the Earth more weakly. The tangential compression effect arises because all parts of the ship are pulled toward the center of the Earth, which corresponds to different force directions for different places.

In your example of a linear spacecraft facing perpendicular to its separation from the Earth, people at the edges would feel a gravitational pull toward the center of the spacecraft, due to the tangential compressive tides.

Potentially, if the length of the spacecraft is comparable to its distance from the Earth's center, they could also feel the stretching longitudinal tidal force, which would pull them toward the "dark side" of the spacecraft (away from the Earth).

##### However, a linear spacecraft facing perpendicular to its separation from the Earth is in an unstable configuration.

If the craft were to rotate slightly such that one end is closer to the Earth, then that edge would be pulled more strongly while the other is pulled more weakly, and the rotation would be amplified.

The simplest stable configuration is a synchronous [tidal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking), where the linear spacecraft always faces toward (or away from) the Earth. As it completes a circular orbit, it would rotate at the same rate.

If the spacecraft is on a non-circular orbit, other tidal-locking configurations are possible, but the general rule is that each time the spacecraft is closest to the Earth, it should be facing toward (or away from) the Earth and rotating at a rate close to the angular speed of its orbit.